# Xcode - Generate nib from xib

Tags: xcode, xib

I have several xib files in my project stored in a bundle.
The problem I have is that when compiling my project, Xcode does not generate all the nib files for each xib.
Things that I've tried:

- Removing the xib files and adding them back (I thought that it might be a reference problem).

What else could it be ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "Xcode does not generate all the nib files for each xib"? Do you not see the screens, when you run app? Please add code where you load these XIBs.

Comment: I load them programmatically using: [self loadNib:@"layout.xib"]. I have the xib files in the bundle and I get just the nib files for tvOS. The other xib files are for iOS and somehow xcode does not generate the corresponding nib files for them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. In the `Project Navigator` select the root of the project
2. then select your target
3. Select `Build Phases`
4. Open the `Copy Bundle Resources` section

Now make sure your resources are in this list. If not add them using the + button.

Comment: They are there. I just noticed that the nibs that are generated are all for tvos (that being also the platform for which I am building the app) and the other xib files are for iOS. Is there a setting that needs to be changed so that the xib files are also generated even if the platform is AppleTV OS ?

Comment: @Dan: When you select a xib open the `Utilities > File Inspector` panel (on the right side of Xcode). Look at the `Target Membership` section. Are both targets checked?